# Nepali/Hindi Keyboard for specific input in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, custom-keyboard

Is it possible to show Nepali/Hindi keyboard by default when a specific TextInput is focused in React native? 
I have an app that is primarily in Nepali. I want to make it possible for users to input data in Nepali in a TextInput. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a wrapper over [indic](https://gitlab.com/indicproject/indic-keyboard) keyboard,

> Indic Keyboard is a versatile keyboard for Android users who wish to use Indic and Indian languages to type messages, compose emails and generally prefer to use them in addition to English on their phone. You can use this application to type anywhere in your phone that you would normally type in English. It currently supports 23 languages and 54 layouts.